# Uneven character line split

Tags: python, split, delimiter

I am having a problem building on some code I have used previously. I have an input file containing 6 pieces of data per row. Problem is that there is not always whitespace to use as a delimiter to split each row up and I also want to split the row in uneven steps of 4/4/4/8/8/4 characters i.e. so:

```
'   0   0 -16-50.6123 115.393   2'
```

would be split into (0,0,-16,-50.6123,115.393,2). I then use this data to form a dictionary where the key is an array of the first three numbers [0,0,-16] and the return value is an array of the final three numbers [-50.6123,115.393,2].

The code I used before when my data was always separated by whitespace (which I can't change since it comes from elsewhere) was as below. Is there a nice way to modify the code I already have to accommodate the new uneven splitting of the lines.

Thanks!

```
def formatter(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip(): continue
        yield [to_float(item) for item in line.split()]

dct1 = {}
with open('test.txt') as f1:
    for row in formatter(f1):
        dct1[tuple(row[:3])] = row[3:6]
```

Comment: find the delimiter or use slices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the slice widths, I'd just chop up the line into the slices. This should give you an idea:

```
my_string ='   0   0 -16-50.6123 115.393   2'
widths=[4,4,4,8,8,4]
my_start=0
my_end=0
for w in widths:
     my_end+=w
     print my_string[my_start:my_end] #or do whatever you want
     my_start+=w
```

output:

```
   0
   0
 -16
-50.6123
 115.393
   2
```